# Force update before insert with EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an already persisted entity with EclipseLink. I perform some changes on it that cause a constraint violation because of the inserting before updating.

As stated in the documentation the operations are performed in the following order Insert/Update/Delete. There is a method that permits for the delete to be executed first but I can't find any solution to make an update execute before insert. Is there some workaround so I could maybe redefine the order like Delete/Update/Insert?

Comment: JPA/EclipseLink orders inserts/updates based on constraints, so if you are using the same EntityManager, they should be arranged correctly for you.  Can you describe what you are doing in more detail?  You can always force statements to be executed using the em.flush() api.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there's no such way, as it doesn't make much sense. If you change the order, it still will fail, since the insert will be issued anyway.

You need to check your business logic and try to always get your entity from DB first.